# Any laptops with curved keyboards?

Tags: laptop, keyboard, acer-aspire, ergonomics

My wife has an old-ish Acer Aspire.  She really likes the slightly-curved keyboard.  However, the newer models I've looked at don't seem to have this anymore.

Her current laptop is on the way out, and we're looking for a replacement in case this one bites the dust.  Are there any current (December 2010) laptops that have an integrated keyboard with a curve to it?

Any brand is fine.  She's looking to run Windows 7 (not on a VM ;) ).

Thanks!

Comment: I've never ever heard of a laptop with a curved keyboard, but it's a great thought. +1!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather an odd/extreme suggestion, but some users really do this and swear by it:

**Buy a rare FingerWorks MacNTouch keyboard and use that to replace the physical keyboard in your laptop.**

A MacNTouch is a completely flat multitouch typing and gesturing surface that plugs into any computer via USB. Works with Windows, Mac, and Linux, without needing to install any drivers.

They aren't available new anymore because Apple bought FingerWorks some years back and used the technology to create the iPhone. But you can buy one used ([this one comes with a housing that you can take apart](http://cgi.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=250607677460)) - they're on eBay every once in a while.

There's a [support community](http://fingerfans.dreamhosters.com) for those crazy enough to go this way :-)